# Is it possibly to install Ubuntu without making partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, disk-usage

I'd like to make dual-boot (Windows 8 + Ubuntu) for my pc, which has a second HDD. Is it possible to simply install Ubuntu on the second one (which is empty) without making any shrinks/partitions?

And is it possible to make Ubuntu use only the second disk without even touching first one (possessed by Windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install.

As you said you have second hard-disk which you want to use only for Ubuntu. while coming to partition step choose manual.

Then choose your 2nd Harddisk which is usually `/dev/sdb` then make it as `root` partition with mount point `/`  thats it.

Now Ubuntu will install in that total harddisk(2nd one) and total space will be for Ubuntu only.

@OP : [Recommended partition scheme](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/)

Comment: alright, thank you! btw is it unusual to have the total HHD space for Ubuntu only? is there anything bad in it or people just got used to making partitions instead of giving the whole HDD to the system?

Comment: It is recommended to have at least a swap partition besides root. This can be on the second hdd as well. Also, to boot Ubuntu from the second disk, you can use the bios boot menu to choose the second hdd to avoid putting grub on the first disk.

Comment: @arcadia having a swap is good idea if you are not having suitable RAM or your system supposed to be a server or heavy programmer machine. else swap doesnt matter because in my Multimedia laptop I never seen swap getting used.

Comment: @arcadia actually for every linux installation there is some standard have to follow. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install Ubuntu without partitioning *a* hard disk is to use a VM, which you don't want.  You can install Ubuntu exclusively to your other hard disk, but you must partition it.  A hard disk without a partition is like an encyclopedia without an index or table of contents: useless.  Just use custom partitioning when you are installing Ubuntu and be sure to tell it to install everything (your OS files and your bootloader) onto the correct hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing "making partitions" with "making multiple partitions".

Partitioning is usually necessary, because it reserves space on the hard drive before the first partition for the master boot record, and most computers expect that record to exist in order to boot your computer.

Thus, a standard Ubuntu install will always use at least a "root"-Partition, even if that partition spans the whole hard disk (apart from that very small first part, which usually covers either the first 512 bytes or the first megabyte of the drive). AFAIK, this is what the solution by AgentCool will give you. So you would have your second hard disk "/dev/sdb", and on it your root partition "/dev/sdb1". So no, a standard Ubuntu cannot be installed without partitions.

Besides that, it **is** technically possible for a Linux system to put a file system directly on a whole drive instead of in a partition, just not for the drive that you want to **boot** your Ubuntu from. So you could have an additional data file system on a third hard drive (/dev/sdc) and have the file system directly on /dev/sdc instead of on a partition /dev/sdc1. However, since this is a non-standard approach, most graphical tools will not allow that, and you would have to create the file system manually (e.g. `mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdc`). And even then you have to use the parameter `-F` to force the creation. Once created though, Ubuntu will use this file system just fine.

Answer (score 0):

About your second question on whether putting Ubuntu on your second hard disk while leaving the first one untouched: That is possible, but usually not desirable.

It detail: You can put your Ubuntu partitions on your second hard drive without touching the first drive in the way several posts suggest, but you will need to also tell the installer to install the boot loader on the second hard drive (default is on the MBR of the first drive).

However your computer by default will boot using the boot loader from the **first hard drive**, and thus will continue booting your Windows. To be given the choice to boot either Windows or Ubuntu, you would need to additionally change your BIOS boot settings to boot from the second drive.